# why no compiler error throw when return value in Delegate is not handle in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public delegate int NumberChanger(int n);
    class Program
    {

        static int num = 10;
        public static int AddNum(int p)
        {
            num += p;
            return num;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create delegate instances
            NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger(AddNum);

            //calling the methods using the delegate objects

            nc1(25);//It is return interger value,but WHY NOT SHOW ERROR. ...(1)

            int result=nc1(25); .............................................(2)

            Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Statement 1 and statement 2 are calling same method. but in statement 1 is not handle return. why it is not throw error.

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should the compiler return an error? If you called

```
AddNum(25)
```

would you receive an error? No? then for a simmetrical reason, even calling a delegate ignoring its result shouldn't be an error

(as a sidenote, in many C compilers there is a flag to produce a warning (a warning, not an error) if a function that returns a value is called and the value is ignored, for example in gcc it's `-Wunused-result`. There is nothing similar in C#)

Answer (score 3):

You are not required to use a value just because it is returned from a method.

Just as you can call `Console.ReadKey();` without using the `ConsoleKeyInfo` value that is returned, you can call `nc1(25);` without using the integer that it returns.

This is the same for calling methods directly and using a delegate to call a method.

---

To be allowed to ignore the return value is useful for example for chaining method calls.

The `StringBuilder.Append` method returns the `StringBuilder` object so that you can chain calls:

```
sb.Append('<').Append(num).Append('>');
```

The last `Append` call also returns the `StringBuilder`, but that value is ignored.